# Run Jupyter Notebook on google cloud compute engine instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook

I used to run Jupyter Notebooks from google compute engine instances perfectly few weeks back using external ip and setting up the firewall rules.

I basically used [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/running-jupyter-notebook-in-google-cloud-platform-in-15-min-61e16da34d52) procedure to set it up some time back.

But when I tried today, jupyter notebook wont open. It's just tries loading but doesnt open up. I recreated my instance, rebuilt the firewall rules but it doesnt work.

Is there any more procedure I need to follow to start jupyter notebook from compute engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I turned out it didnt work because of my institute wifi (for some reason I don't know it doesnt allow). It works on using proxy/VPN or other wifi.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

I am also newest in running jupyter-notebook on google cloud, but I used the same tutorial, and it worked to me.

1. Don't you forget to start jupyter-notebook from the computer engine terminal?
2. How do you trying to connect to jupyter-notebook, using http or https? I had similar problem and connecting through http solved it